# How to implement a timer which can be paused in Android? Is CountDownTimer suitable for this task?

Tags: android

I'd like to implement several timers (to create a multiple-stopwatches application), and CountDownTimer seems to be the obvious choice, however I'd like to provide the ability to pause one or all of the stopwatches.

From the documentation provided on [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) I don't see an obvious way to pause the countdown after it has begun, only to stop it or to increase/decrease it by a set amount.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about using the CountDownTimer but I know that when I had to make a timer I used the built in Java Timer class with a TimerTask. If you were wanting to make several timers count down and pause them individually you could do something like this

```
task1 = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                    time1--;
                    }
        };
task2 = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                    time2--;
                    }
        };
        Timer1 = new Timer();
        Timer2 = new Timer();
        Timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1,0,1000);
        Timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(task2,0,1000);

@Override OnClickListener(stopButton1)
{
    Timer.Cancel();
}
@Override OnClickListener(startButton1)
{
    Timer1 = new Timer();
    Timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1,0,1000);
}
```

This isnt exact syntax but I think it relays the idea. Just a heads up but if you go this route you can't update the UI in that task normally, that would look like this.

```
Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      text.setText("Level " + Integer.toString(level)+ " will start in " +Integer.toString(time) + " seceonds." );
    }
});
```

which you would put in the "Run" part of the task. This doesn't really have to do with the exact question but I was stuck for days on updating the UI part until someone here helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

I started out using `CountDownTimer` (but switched to `Runnable` and `Handler.postDelayed`).

On timer ticks I decremented a counter. To pause, I canceled the timer. To resume, I created a *new* timer using the saved counter value. It seemed a little kludgy, but it seemed the only option.

(I don't recall why I made the switch, unfortunately. IIRC at the time there was a reason, but I don't know if it was a limitation of `CountDownTimer`, or my particular needs.)